# Birthday problem variation with non-uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a **birthday problem**: $N$ people have birthdays within year. The distribution of the birthdays is independent among people, not uniform (e.g., could be poisson), with some known CDF $G(x)$.

Consider $q_i$ - a random variable indicating the *number of people*, who had birthdays *before and on the date $i$* (where $i\in(1, 365)$). How to compute  the next day $q_{i+1}$ distribution (number of people who had birthdays **on and before** $i+1$), knowing the distribution of $q_i$ and the distribution $G(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the two events:
$$\{q_i=j,q_{i+1}=l\} \subset \{q_i=j\},$$ with $l\geq j$.

The first event is equivalent to selecting $l$ among $N$ people then assign $j$ of them to be having a early birthday and the rest $l-j$ to be having birthday on $i+1$-th day. So the probability is $$ {N \choose l }G(i+1)^l(1-G(i+1))^{N-l} \times {l \choose j} (G(i)/G(i+1))^j(1-G(i)/G(i+1))^{l-j}.$$

The probability for the second event is easier:
$${N \choose j }G(i)^j (1-G(i))^{N-j}.$$

The ratio of these two probabilities is $$\mathbf P(q_{i+1}=l|q_{i}=j)=\frac{{N \choose l } {l \choose j} }{ {N \choose j } }   \frac{(G(i+1)-G(i))^{l-j} (1-G(i+1))^{N-l}  }{(1-G(i))^{N-j}} ,$$
which can be represented as $j+ Binom(N-j,p) $, where 
$$p=\frac{G(i+1)-G(i) }{ 1-G(i) }.$$

Comment: thanks for the reply @donoho! Do I understand correctly, $\mathbf P(q_{i+1}=l|q_{i}=j)$ can be used to compute $q_{i+1}$ in the following way: $\Pr[q_{i+1}=l] = \sum_{j=0}^{N}\Pr[q_i=j]\Pr[q_{i+1}=l|q_{i}=j]$

Comment: @michael Yes, but you may only need to sum up to $l$ since you know the conditional probability will be zero if $ j>l$.